# Problem when I run the 'artisan:migrate' in a 'Many to One' relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have the 'people' table and each 'person' must have some 'furniture'.

I run 'migrate' and this error message appears:

> QLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `my_database`.`furniture` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `furniture` add constraint
> `furniture_person_id_foreign` foreign key (`person_id`) references
> `people` (`id`))

**LARAVEL VERSION: 5.8**

Here are my files:

**2021_04_15_132404_create_persons_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePeopleTable extends Migration
{
   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('cpf');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->softDeletes();      
            $table->timestamps();          
        });
    }
  
   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('people');
    }
}
```

**2021_04_16_233323_create_furniture_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFurnitureTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('furniture', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('person_id')->unsignedBigInteger()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('person_id')->references('id')->on('people');
            $table->softDeletes();   
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('furniture');
    }
}
```

**Person.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Person extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
  
    
}
```

**Furniture.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Furniture extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$table->integer('person_id')->nullable();` from `CreateFurnitureTable` migration, leave the `unsignedBigInteger` since that's the integer column type. Just using that method us also recommended by Laravel as per the [documentation on foreign keys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) for Laravel 5.8

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('person_id');

$table->foreign('person_id')->references('id')->on('people');
```

Comment: Returned an error message:
Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::foreignId does not exist.

This method may not exist in version 5.8. which is the version I'm using. Is not it?

Comment: Updated answer for Laravel v5.8.